# Processing | Program is lagging

Tags: processing

I'm new to Processing and I need to make a program that, captured the main monitor, shows on the second screen the average color and makes a spiral using another color (perceptual dominant color) get by a function. 
**The problem** is that the program is so slow (lag, 1FPS). I think it's because it has too many things to do everytime i do a screenshot, but I have no idea how to make it faster.

Also there could be many other problems, but the main one is that. 
Thank you very much!

Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.color.ColorSpace;

PImage screenshot; 

float a = 0;
int blockSize = 20;

int avg_c;
int per_c;


void setup() {
  fullScreen(2); // 1920x1080
  noStroke();
  frame.removeNotify();
}

void draw() { 
  screenshot();
  avg_c = extractColorFromImage(screenshot);
  per_c = extractAverageColorFromImage(screenshot);
  background(avg_c); // Average color
  spiral();
}


void screenshot() {
  try{
    Robot robot_Screenshot = new Robot();
    screenshot = new PImage(robot_Screenshot.createScreenCapture
    (new Rectangle(0, 0, displayWidth, displayHeight)));
  }
  catch (AWTException e){ }
  frame.setLocation(displayWidth/2, 0);
}

void spiral() {
  fill (per_c); 
  for (int i = blockSize; i < width; i += blockSize*2)
  {
    ellipse(i, height/2+sin(a+i)*100, blockSize+cos(a+i)*5, blockSize+cos(a+i)*5);    
    a += 0.001;
  }
}


color extractColorFromImage(PImage screenshot) { // Get average color
    screenshot.loadPixels(); 
    int r = 0, g = 0, b = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < screenshot.pixels.length; i++) { 
        color c = screenshot.pixels[i]; 
        r += c>>16&0xFF; 
        g += c>>8&0xFF; 
        b += c&0xFF;
    } 
    r /= screenshot.pixels.length; g /= screenshot.pixels.length; b /= screenshot.pixels.length;
    return color(r, g, b);
}

color extractAverageColorFromImage(PImage screenshot) { // Get lab average color (perceptual)
  float[] average = new float[3];
  CIELab lab = new CIELab();

  int numPixels = screenshot.pixels.length;
  for (int i = 0; i < numPixels; i++) {
    color rgb = screenshot.pixels[i];

    float[] labValues = lab.fromRGB(new float[]{red(rgb),green(rgb),blue(rgb)});

    average[0] += labValues[0];
    average[1] += labValues[1];
    average[2] += labValues[2];
  }

  average[0] /= numPixels;
  average[1] /= numPixels;
  average[2] /= numPixels;

  float[] rgb = lab.toRGB(average);

  return color(rgb[0] * 255,rgb[1] * 255, rgb[2] * 255);
}


public class CIELab extends ColorSpace {

    @Override
    public float[] fromCIEXYZ(float[] colorvalue) {
        double l = f(colorvalue[1]);
        double L = 116.0 * l - 16.0;
        double a = 500.0 * (f(colorvalue[0]) - l);
        double b = 200.0 * (l - f(colorvalue[2]));
        return new float[] {(float) L, (float) a, (float) b};
    }

    @Override
    public float[] fromRGB(float[] rgbvalue) {
        float[] xyz = CIEXYZ.fromRGB(rgbvalue);
        return fromCIEXYZ(xyz);
    }

    @Override
    public float getMaxValue(int component) {
        return 128f;
    }

    @Override
    public float getMinValue(int component) {
        return (component == 0)? 0f: -128f;
    }    

    @Override
    public String getName(int idx) {
        return String.valueOf("Lab".charAt(idx));
    }

    @Override
    public float[] toCIEXYZ(float[] colorvalue) {
        double i = (colorvalue[0] + 16.0) * (1.0 / 116.0);
        double X = fInv(i + colorvalue[1] * (1.0 / 500.0));
        double Y = fInv(i);
        double Z = fInv(i - colorvalue[2] * (1.0 / 200.0));
        return new float[] {(float) X, (float) Y, (float) Z};
    }

    @Override
    public float[] toRGB(float[] colorvalue) {
        float[] xyz = toCIEXYZ(colorvalue);
        return CIEXYZ.toRGB(xyz);
    }

    CIELab() {
        super(ColorSpace.TYPE_Lab, 3);
    }

    private double f(double x) {
        if (x > 216.0 / 24389.0) {
            return Math.cbrt(x);
        } else {
            return (841.0 / 108.0) * x + N;
        }
    }

    private double fInv(double x) {
        if (x > 6.0 / 29.0) {
            return x*x*x;
        } else {
            return (108.0 / 841.0) * (x - N);
        }
    }


    private final ColorSpace CIEXYZ =
        ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_CIEXYZ);

    private final double N = 4.0 / 29.0;
}
```

Comment: Calculating `per_c` is killing your performance. That is the line where you can gain some FPS.

Comment: @laancelot Oh ok, thanks. There is anything I can do to keep the result improving my code?

Comment: Fortunately, yes. I'll write you something up in a minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's lots that can be done, even beyond what's already been mentioned.

### Iteration & Threading

After taking the screenshot, immediately iterate over every 1/N pixels (perhaps every 4 or 8) of the buffered image. Then, during this iteration, calculate the LAB value for each pixel (as you have each pixel channel directly available), and meanwhile increment the running total of each RGB channel.

This saves us from iterating over the same pixels twice and avoids unncessary conversions (`BufferedImage` → `PImage`; and composing then decomposing pixel channels from `PImage` pixels).

Likewise, we avoid Processing's expensive `resize()` call (as suggested in another answer), which is not something we want to call every frame (even though it does speed the program up, it's not an efficient method).

Now, on top of iteration change, we can wrap the iteration in a `Callable` to easily run the workload across multiple system threads concurrently (after all, pixel iteration is *embarrassingly parallel*); the example below does this with 2 threads, each screenshotting and processing half of the display's pixels.

### Optimise RGB→XYZ→LAB conversion

*We're not so concerned about the backwards conversion since that's only done for one value per frame*

It looks like you've implemented XYZ→LAB yourself and are using the RGB→XYZ converter from `java.awt.color`.

As has been identified, the forward conversion XYZ→LAB uses a `cbrt()` which is as a bottleneck. I also imagine that the RGB→XYZ implementation makes 3 calls to `Math.Pow(x, 2.4)` — 3 non-integer exponents per pixel adds considerably to the computation. The solution is faster math...

#### Jafama

[Jafama](https://github.com/jeffhain/jafama) is a drop-in `java.math` replacement -- simply import the library and replace any `Math.__()` calls with `FastMath.__()` for a free speedup (you could go even further by trading Jafama's E-15 precision with less accurate and even faster dedicated LUT-based classes).

So at the very least, swap out `Math.cbrt()` for `FastMath.cbrt()`. Then consider implementing RGB→XYZ yourself ([example](https://github.com/micycle1/PeasyGradients/blob/ddf13bc5d9723dade45b5a7e5c63a673b834d004/src/main/micycle/peasygradients/colorspace/XYZ.java)), again using Jafama in place of `java.math`.

---

You may even find that for such a project, converting to XYZ only is a sufficient color space to work with to overcome the well known weaknesses with RGB (and therefore save yourself from the XYZ→LAB conversion).

### Cache LAB Calculation

Unless *most* pixels are changing *every* frame, then consider caching the LAB value for every pixel, recalculating it only when the pixel has changed between the current the previous frames. The tradeoff here is the overhead from checking every pixel against its previous value, versus how much calculation positive checks will save. Given that the LAB calculation is much more expensive it's very worthwhile here. The example below uses this technique.

### Screen Capture

No matter how well optimised the rest of the program is, a considerable bottleneck is the AWT Robot's `createScreenCapture()`. It will struggles to go past 30FPS on large enough displays. I can't offer any exact advice but it's worth looking at other screen capture methods in Java.

### Reworked code with iteration changes & threading

This code implements what has discussed above minus any changes to the LAB calculation.

```
float a = 0;
int blockSize = 20;

int avg_c;
int per_c;

java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService threadPool = java.util.concurrent.Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

List<java.util.concurrent.Callable<Boolean>> taskList;

float[] averageLAB;
int totalR = 0, totalG = 0, totalB = 0; 

CIELab lab = new CIELab();

final int pixelStride = 8; // look at every 8th pixel


void setup() {
  size(800, 800, FX2D);
  noStroke();
  frame.removeNotify();

  taskList = new ArrayList<java.util.concurrent.Callable<Boolean>>();

  Compute thread1 = new Compute(0, 0, width, height/2);
  Compute thread2 = new Compute(0, height/2, width, height/2);
  taskList.add(thread1);
  taskList.add(thread2);
}

void draw() { 

  totalR = 0; // re init
  totalG = 0; // re init
  totalB = 0; // re init 
  averageLAB = new float[3]; // re init

  final int numPixels = (width*height)/pixelStride;

  try {
    threadPool.invokeAll(taskList); // run threads now and block until completion of all
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  // calculate average LAB
  averageLAB[0]/=numPixels;
  averageLAB[1]/=numPixels;
  averageLAB[2]/=numPixels;

  final float[] rgb = lab.toRGB(averageLAB);
  per_c = color(rgb[0] * 255, rgb[1] * 255, rgb[2] * 255);

  // calculate average RGB
  totalR/=numPixels;
  totalG/=numPixels;
  totalB/=numPixels;

  avg_c = color(totalR, totalG, totalB);

  background(avg_c); // Average color
  spiral();
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  text(frameRate, 10, 20);
}

class Compute implements java.util.concurrent.Callable<Boolean> {

  private final Rectangle screenRegion;
  private Robot robot_Screenshot;
  private final int[] previousRGB;
  private float[][] previousLAB;

  Compute(int x, int y, int w, int h) {

    screenRegion = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);

    previousRGB = new int[w*h];
    previousLAB = new float[w*h][3];

    try {
      robot_Screenshot = new Robot();
    } 
    catch (AWTException e1) {
      e1.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  @Override
    public Boolean call() {

    BufferedImage rawScreenshot = robot_Screenshot.createScreenCapture(screenRegion);  

    int[] ssPixels = new int[rawScreenshot.getWidth()*rawScreenshot.getHeight()]; // screenshot pixels

    rawScreenshot.getRGB(0, 0, rawScreenshot.getWidth(), rawScreenshot.getHeight(), ssPixels, 0, rawScreenshot.getWidth()); // copy buffer to int[] array

    for (int pixel = 0; pixel < ssPixels.length; pixel+=pixelStride) {

      // get invididual colour channels
      final int pixelColor = ssPixels[pixel];
      final int R = pixelColor >> 16 & 0xFF;
      final int G = pixelColor >> 8 & 0xFF;
      final int B = pixelColor & 0xFF;

      if (pixelColor != previousRGB[pixel]) { // if pixel has changed recalculate LAB value
        float[] labValues = lab.fromRGB(new float[]{R/255f, G/255f, B/255f}); // note that I've fixed this; beforehand you were missing the /255, so it was always white.
        previousLAB[pixel] = labValues;
      }

      averageLAB[0] += previousLAB[pixel][0];
      averageLAB[1] += previousLAB[pixel][1];
      averageLAB[2] += previousLAB[pixel][2];

      totalR+=R;
      totalG+=G;
      totalB+=B;

      previousRGB[pixel] = pixelColor; // cache last result
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

800x800px;  pixelStride = 4; fairly static screen background

[image]

Comment: I've just re-read this answer and it's soood good! (+1)

Answer (score 3):

Yeesh, about 1 FPS on my machine:

[image: About 1 FPS]

To optimize code can be really hard, so instead of reading everything looking for stuff to improve, I started by testing where you were losing so much processing power. The answer was at this line:

```
per_c = extractAverageColorFromImage(screenshot);
```

The `extractAverageColorFromImage` method is well written, but it underestimate the amount of work it has to do. There is a quadratic relationship between the size of a screen and the number of pixels in this screen, so the bigger the screen the worst the situation. And this method is processing every pixel of the screenshot all the time, several time per screenshot.

This is a lot of work for an average color. Now, if there was a way to cut some corners... maybe a smaller screen, or a smaller screenshot... oh! there is! Let's resize the screenshot. After all, we don't need to go into such details as individual pixels for an average. In the `screenshot` method, add this line:

```
void screenshot() {
  try {
    Robot robot_Screenshot = new Robot();
    screenshot = new PImage(robot_Screenshot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(0, 0, displayWidth, displayHeight)));
    // ADD THE NEXT LINE
    screenshot.resize(width/4, height/4);
  }
  catch (AWTException e) {
  }
  frame.setLocation(displayWidth/2, 0);
}
```

I divided the workload by 4, but I encourage you to tweak this number until you have the fastest satisfying result you can. This is just a proof of concept:

[image: 10x faster!]

As you can see, resizing the screenshot and making it 4x smaller gives me 10x more speed. That's not a miracle, but it's much better, and I can't see a difference in the end result - but about that part, you'll have to use your own judgement, as you are the one who knows what your project is about. Hope it'll help!

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try to adjust my code now :))

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately I can't provide a detailed answer like laancelot (+1), but hopefully I can provide a few tips:

1. Resizing the image is definitely a good direction. Bare in mind you can also skip a number of pixels instead of incrementing every single pixel. (if you handle the pixel indices correctly, you can get a similar effect to resize without calling resize, though that won't save you a lot CPU time)
2. Don't create a new `Robot` instance multiple times a second. Create it once in setup and re-use it. (This is more of a good habit to get into)
3. Use a CPU profiler, such as the one in [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) to see what exactly is slow and aim to optimise the slowest stuff first.

**point 1** example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numPixels; i+= 100)
```

**point 2** example:

```
Robot robot_Screenshot;
...
void setup() {
  fullScreen(2); // 1920x1080
  noStroke();
  frame.removeNotify();
  try{
    robot_Screenshot = new Robot();
  }catch(AWTException e){
    println("error setting up screenshot Robot instance");
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
...
void screenshot() {
  screenshot = new PImage(robot_Screenshot.createScreenCapture
    (new Rectangle(0, 0, displayWidth, displayHeight)));
  frame.setLocation(displayWidth/2, 0);
}
```

**point 3 example:**
[image: VisualVM CPU profiler]

Notice the slowest bit are actually AWT's **fromRGB** and `Math.cbrt()`
I'd suggest finding another alternative `RGB -> XYZ -> L*a*b*` conversion method that is simpler (mainly functions, less classes, with AWT or other dependencies) and hopefully faster.

Comment: I love the idea to skip some of the pixels! I though about something in the same lines but doubted about the way it would sample the pixels - although I can't see how this could go wrong. Now I'm thinking about using a CPU profiler myself, too. Great advices.

Comment: Yes, that's right, when skipping pixels like that it's good to manage the indices to sample somewhat uniformly, otherwise some areas might get oversampled and others undersampled. CPU profiler is handy: I had suprises with bits of code that were unexpectedly slow and found same functions to be faster on different operating systems. Also the memory profiler is quite handy to spot memory leaks.